# Replace Ubuntu 12.04 on my USB Pendrive with latest Ubuntu version

Tags: usb, usb-drive

I need to remove Ubuntu 12.04 from my USB Pendrive so that I can add latest Ubuntu version instead.

I tried updating from 12.04 to Ubuntu 14 using the update manager but I dont have enough free storage on my USB.

How do I remove the old version and replace it with the new one?

**Edit:**

I managed to update to Ubuntu 16.04.3 by using the [UniversalUSBInstaller](https://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/). I didn't format the USB beforehand. Instead the UniversalUSBInstaller overwrote the old Ubuntu 12.04. It seems to be working ok atm. If there's problems, I'll post back here. Thanks for your help.

Comment: "How do I remove the old version and replace it with the new one?"  The same way you installed 12.04 ;-)

Comment: Disk Utility is for Mac , i m using Windows. Im worried that If I right click the usb and select format fat32 that it will reset the usb to be storage only. I need it to remain bootable. Can anyone confirm that the usb will remain bootable

Answer (score 2):

### Single boot USB pendrive

A cloned live-only Ubuntu system on a USB pendrive is the basic and standard system.

An alternative is a persistent live Ubuntu system, where you can install program packages, that survive reboot, and where you can store data files.

Such systems can be installed [almost] automatically, if you use **[mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb)** to install Ubuntu into the pendrive. The previous content of the USB pendrive will be lost during that process, but some fragments might be possible to recover. If you want to remove all traces, you should [wipe](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/wipe) the whole drive before installing.

A live-only system can also be cloned with the built-in tool (in Ubuntu), **Disks** alias `gnome-disks`, and *in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS* and newer versions, the **Startup Disk Creator**, and with **[Win32 Disk Imager](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Win32DiskImager/iso2usb)** in Windows.

### Multiboot USB pendrive

If you have/want a multiboot USB pendrive with several live operating systems, you can use another tool, for example **[MultiBootUSB](http://multibootusb.org/)**.

Comment: @frustrationmultiplied, Then I would recommend that you install mkusb and use it to create a persistent live system, https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/persistent ; You can get a system with mkusb in a 'two step procedure, when starting from Windows. (The advantage is that mkusb creates a partition for persistence, and it is not limited to 4 GB as a file in a FAT32 file system.

Comment: do you know If I right click the usb and select format fat32 will it reset the usb to be storage only. I need it to remain bootable. mkusb looks complicated

Comment: In Windows? You can use the standard tool to 'format' the USB drive, and I think it will let you select file system (at least in some versions of Windows). -- But mkusb is making things easy when you have it installed. The cloning alternative will not create a persistent live system.

Comment: Yes windows. Do i just right click the drive

Comment: We are no experts on Windows. I think it might work. Try :-)

Comment: regarding mkusb, do i need to install it in my present ubuntu 12.04 and then use it to upgrade to ubuntu 16

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72352/discussion-between-sudodus-and-frustrationmultiplied).

Comment: I managed to update to ubuntu 16.04.3 by using the UniversalUSBInstaller. I didnt format the USB beforehand. Instead the UniversalUSBInstaller overwritted old Ubuntu 12.04. It seems to be working ok atm. if theres problems ill post back here. Thanks for your help

Comment: +1 because you deserve more points than me :) Along the theme of this question have you given any thought to 18.04 LTS Bionic Beaver daily builds repeatedly overriding first part of USB but persistent storage is preserved for installed apps and `~` directory? I guess parts of `/etc/...` need to be preserved too such as `rc.local` and `.../default/grub` but I have no idea how to tackle that part.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix, I reply to you at the Ubuntu Forums :-)

Answer (score 1):

**Linux**

If you are already on ubuntu or any other linux system you can do this.

do `lsblk`

and that should list every device that is plugged into your system.

You need the ISO of the version of ubuntu that you wanna use.

`dd if=(/PATH/FILENAME) of=/dev/(The name of the device in lsblk. Like sdc)`

This will write over the files in it and you now have a flashdrive with it.

**Windows**

Just get UUI from [here](https://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/)

Comment: What is `THE PACE OF THE ISO`? Did you mean PATH? In any respect wouldn't it be /PATH/FILENAME?

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Thank you, I've made some changes.

Comment: My pleasure. Welcome to **Ask Ubuntu**. Looking forward to seeing more of your contributions in the future.